# Como remover esse URL DATA 64 e deixar url normal do arquivo

Tags: javascript, html, url

Quando eu faço *upload* de uma imagem, ele adiciona uma sequência de letras, números e caracteres na URL. Eu gostaria de saber como faço para mudar isso, tipo, ao invés de aparece esse tanto de caracteres, simplesmente aparecer o link da imagem.

Segue abaixo o código JavaScript que estou utilizando:

```
$(document).on('change', '#image-upload', function(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

        // Only process image files.
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }

        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
            return function(e) {
                // Render thumbnail.
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                span.innerHTML =
                        '<a href="javascript:;" class="add-image"><img width="100px" height="100px" class="image-thumb" src="' + e.target.result + '" title="' + escape(theFile.name) + '"/></a>'
                        ;
                $("#memes-custom").append(span);
            };
        })(f);

        // Read in the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
});
```

Comment: A url só poderá existir, se o arquivo for salvo no servidor. Enquanto ele está apenas no browser, carregado pelo javascript será exibido os dados do arquivo nesse formato Data64

Comment: O problema é que não existe link. Esses caracteres são justamente o conteúdo da imagem. Você precisaria salvar a imagem no servidor para conseguir o resultado que quer.

Comment: Eu removi a tag PHP pois não parecia ter relação com a pergunta, mas você pode fazer uma requisição assíncrona para um script PHP que efetua a escrita desta imagem em arquivo e gere a URL final, como já comentado pelos colegas. O envio de um arquivo com AJAX e PHP é constantemente discutido aqui e você encontrará muitas perguntas para te auxiliar neste processo.

Comment: que tipo de alteração eu fazeria neste codigo?  Estou tendo muita dificuldade com isso!